# convert buffer to binary in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am using axios to request an image from a url like this:

```
const response = await axios.get('https://asite.dom/image/url', { responseType: 'arrayBuffer' });
```

I don't need and don't want to save the file locally. I just need the plain binary data for checking the image dimensions.

Thus I don't want to do this

```
const bufferImage = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary');
```

because that's a buffer not the binary data.

I've tried to access

```
response.data
```

directly, but that's not the image's binary data either.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just tested this and it works:

```js
const response = await axios.get(
  'https://example.com/image.png', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }
); 

const bin = response.data.toString('binary');
console.log(bin);
```

The key seems to be that you capitalized the `b` in `arraybuffer`. Also, `response.data` is already a buffer, so you can just directly convert it to a string.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.

Comment: OMG. THANK YOU! I've spent a day and a half trying to find the right combination. I think a lot of places have the uppercase b in the documentation